# ContentResolver insert method occur java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android

```
private static void insertAlbumArt(@NonNull Context context, int albumId, String path) {
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

Uri artworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
Log.d("-------------", artworkUri.toString());
contentResolver.delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(artworkUri, albumId), null, null);

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("album_id", albumId);
values.put("_data", path);

contentResolver.insert(artworkUri, values);
}
```

This code for add album of music player but error occur.

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MIME type application/octet-stream cannot be inserted into content://media/external/audio/albumart; expected MIME type under image/***

Why this occur and what is solution?

Comment: That is "path"?

Comment: Yes it is. content://media/external/audio/albumart

Comment: Well... add a mime type i would say.

Comment: Could you tell me more detail?

Comment: How can I add subject to mms?